# What's wrong with this C++ code lottery guessing game?

Tags: procedural-programming

I am making a simple lottery game application, where three random numbers between 0 and 10 are generated, if the user gets all three in the right order, they get 1 million. If they get one right then they win 10 dollars, and if they get all three but not in order, they win a thousand, if two are matching then they get $1,000. and if they get none right then they get nothing.

Here's my code here.

int main()
{

```
cout << "Hello, this is the lottery! Three random numbers between 0 and 10 will be generated. Guess what they are and the order!" << endl;
char answer;
cout << "Do you want to play? (y or n): " << endl;
cin >> answer;
while (answer == 'y' || 'Y')

{
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    int ran1 = rand() % 10;
    int ran2 = rand() % 10;
    int ran3 = rand() % 10;
    int guess1, guess2, guess3;
    cout << "Enter your first number guess: " << endl;
    cin >> guess1;
    cout << "Enter your second number guess: " << endl;
    cin >> guess2;
    cout << "Enter your third number guess: " << endl;
    cin >> guess3;
    if ((guess1 != ran1 || ran2 || ran3) && (guess2 != ran1 || ran2 || ran3) && (guess3 != ran1 || ran2 || ran3))
        cout << "You won no money. Sucks for you." << endl;
    else
        if ((guess1 == ran1 || ran2 || ran3) || (guess2 == ran1 || ran2 || ran3) || (guess3 == ran1 || ran2) || ran3)
            cout << "You won 10 dollars!" << endl;
        else
            if ((guess1 && guess2 == ran1 && ran2) || (guess1 && guess3 == ran1 && ran3) || (guess2 && guess3 == ran2 && ran3))
                cout << "You won 100 dollars!" << endl;
            else
                if ((guess1 == ran1 || ran2 || ran3) && (guess2 == ran1 || ran2 || ran3) && (guess3 == ran1 || ran2 || ran3))
                    cout << "You won 1 thousand dollars! good job!" << endl;
                else
                    if ((guess1 == ran1) && (guess2 == ran2) && (guess3 == ran3))
                        cout << "You won 1 million dollars! jackpot!" << endl;

    cout << "The numbers were " << ran1 << "," << ran2 << "," << ran3 << endl;
    cout << "Play again?(y or n): " << endl;
    cin >> answer;
    if (answer == 'y')
        continue;
    else
        break;

}



cout << "Game Over" << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

when i run this code, things don't go right with the decisions.  All it says is "You won no money. sucks for you".  Idk what's wrong maybe its something simple but can someone help? Thanks.

Comment: `guess1 != ran1 || ran2 || ran3` doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: what's wrong with it?

Comment: see Sadovsky's answer below, also you should switch the order of your `if`s, as it is, even if you got all guesses right, you'd win $10 because it satisfies the condition (and its before it)

Comment: so what order should they be in? they were in a different order before but it still didn't work right

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((guess1 != ran1 || ran2 || ran3) && (guess2 != ran1 || ran2 || ran3) && (guess3 != ran1 || ran2 || ran3))
```

should be

```
if ((guess1 != ran1 || guess1 != ran2 || guess1 != ran3) && (guess2 != ran1 || guess2 != ran2 || guess2 != ran3) && (guess3 != ran1 || guess3 != ran2 || guess3 != ran3))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not the order of the conditionals, even though there are flaws there as well, but is the way in which you have written the conditionals.

(guess1 == ran1 || ran2) is different than (guess1 == ran1 || guess1 == ran2)

This is because in c++ a number other than 0 evaluates to true. This is why it is evaluating to true every time.

For example, say guess1 = 1, ran1 = 2, and ran2 = 3, then

(guess1 == ran1 || guess1 == ran2) will evaluate to false, but

(guess1 == ran1 || ran2) will evaluate to true.